# Is it possible to create Surface from internal/external mesh faces ONLY, using Python scripts in Abaqus 6.14?

Tags: python, plugins, simulation, abaqus

I am working on Abaqus 6.14 plugin, which is intended to automate as much repetitive job in numerical model preparation as possible, as running dozens of similiar simulations is part of my Engineer's Thesis. Another step I am trying to automate is creating Surfaces on multiple parts from internal and external faces of the parts' meshes separately. The reason why I need this is that during simulation, some elements are being deleted due to material failure an setting collisions on internal surfaces is necessary to prevent objects from overlapping. I cannot simply select ALL mesh faces, which is relatively easy to achieve, as internal faces must have different side selected.

If the faces are selected manually, the user is able to determine whether to select external faces only, internal faces only, or both - however, [Abaqus scripting reference guide](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm) seem to not provide a method allowing to achieve such a result with Python scripts.

I have also tried to analyze both Abaqus.rpy and journal file, but depending on session settings, they both include face selection depending either on masks or face indexes, which is useless in my case, especially as I will need to run such simulations with meshes consisting of hundreds of thousands of elements and the parts are of irregular shape.

Another approach I tried was to decompile Abaqus CAE's *.pyc files and trying to determine which internal methods are responsible for filtering faces or setting such filters in the GUI, although without success.

My question is: is there any way to create such surfaces with Python scripts, which would be independent from part geometry, element types, mesh elements number, meshing technique etc?

Comment: Are you predefining the potential failure surfaces during preprocessing, or are you also using this data as input to an analysis subroutine?

Comment: The contact surfaces (both external and internal) are predefined during preprocessing, and they are not being changed later. Basically each part has two contact surfaces: internal and external mesh faces, and contact is set between all sets from all parts as contact pairs. This is done so because it was the only way it **worked** for model already created (although fully manually) - other approaches resulted with overlapping after first element failures, which led to severe errors of course.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question. Do you simpy wan't to distinguish betweeb faces that are on an external surface and faces inside the modell? Like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609481/abaqus-a-way-to-localize-external-nodes/43620189#43620189

Comment: Roughly, but I also need to make one step further. For each part I need to distinguish external/internal MeshFaces and create two separate mesh-based Surface objects out of them, in order to set interactions.

I think I might give your solution a try in order to obtain the proper MeshFace/MeshElement objects. Then I'll try again to create desired Surface objects out of them. The thing is Abaqus requires programmer to create Surface from MeshElementArrays, not MeshFaceArrays, which seems a lot more intuitive to me as I could simply specify SIDE1 and SIDE2 MeshFaces, just like geometry Faces.